# Syntax error on with only when specifying open() mode

Tags: python, python-2.7, with-statement

I have the following file:

```
import sys

lines = []
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f: #this works fine
    for line in f:
        lines.append(line.replace('\\', '/')
with open(sys.argv[1], 'w') as f: #this gives a syntax error
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line)
```

Whenever I try to run it, I get a syntax error on the `with` part of the second `with` statement:

```
  File "ChangeSlashes.py", line 7
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'w') as f:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why is this happening, and why is it only when I specify the mode in `open()`?

Comment: `lines.append(line.replace('\\', '/')` didnt close parens on previous line.

Comment: @PaulRooney Of course. And here I was thinking it's some obscure version difference thing or something.

Comment: Its a shame it can't point to the line with the problem. I get this issue all the time particularly with IDE's that swallow parens. You just learn to look for it after a while though.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
lines.append(line.replace('\\', '/')
```

with:

```
lines.append(line.replace('\\', '/'))
```